# Round edged-curved mesh from CAD-Program

Tags: mesh

How can I round this curved mesh?
I tried to subdivide the faces, didnt work.
Bevel also didnt work.

I dont know how to do it. Anyone has a tipp for me?

The model was created in Fusion360 and imported as a .stl file.

Kind regards

[image]

[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: You could try mesh/clean up/ limited dissolve with a low max angle to un-triangulate the faces, then bevel should work.

Comment: @francoisgibon I tried it, but it doesn't work. I beveled it, I also had a lot more faces but the object was edged as before.... I don't know. I un-tringulated it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can smooth the model by going to Mesh -> shade smooth in Object mode or selecting faces in Edit mode and choosing Face -> shade smooth.

However, as others have pointed out, you seem to have some redundant edges (edges that do not change the shape of the model). Even if they change the shape slightly, it is not noticeable. You can remove every other edge by selecting the edge ring (select an edge, hold CTRL + ALT, and select a parallel edge) and choosing Select
 -> Checker Deselect. I think which edges are deselected is based on the active edge (the last edge you select), so if you would prefer the compliment edges were deselected, undo and shift-select any edge in the edge ring you want to be deselected before running it again. When you have the edges you want to delete selected...delete them.

Fun fact: changing the settings for Checker Deselect will allow you to deselect every Nth edge, N being whatever number you like; third edge, fourth edge, etc.